# Dynamically generate Waveform.js .each() - Replace document.getElementByID with something specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, waveform, soundmanager2

I am trying to generate a waveform via waveform.js for each instance of a soundcloud/soundmanager2 link.

Everything works except I can't figure out how to set the container to something other than document.getElementByID('idname') as that just finds the first instance.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
               $(".player").each(function() {

                var $el = $(this),
                $sctrackid = $el.attr('data-sc-id');

                    SC.get('/tracks/'+$sctrackid, function(tracks) {

                        var waveform = new Waveform({
                        container: document.getElementById("waveform"),
                        innerColor: "#333"

                    });

                   waveform.dataFromSoundCloudTrack(tracks);


                });
            });
```

So what works is that it does correctly pull the different waveforms dynamically, it just loads them all into the first instance of "example3" on the page.

What I need is a way to set the container to something like: $el.find('#waveform')

But obviously that doesn't work. What's the right syntax for the 'container: ' to reference a specific div that is a child of '$el' ?

Comment: I figured out a fix temporarily assigning the $sctrackid to a div id and the calling that variable in the getElementByID, but I'd prefer something still based on the $el var so I can be more flexible and not have to rely on the track id info.